# Jupyter notebook can't find pyxlsb module

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, xlsb

I'm trying to use the pyxlsb module in Jupyter Notebook but it comes up with:

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pyxlsb'

for the line of code:

`from pyxlsb import open_workbook as open_xlsb`

Would anyone be able to tell me why, and ideally a fix for it please?

Comment: You will need to install it. You can use pip install pyxlsb to achieve that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`pyxlsb` might not be installed in your ipython environment.

A) Try running the following code at the command line:

```
$ pip install pyxlsb
```

B) Run a bash commands in jupyter using `%%bash` magic

C) Use pip inside the notebook as follows:

```
!pip install pyxlsb
```

Comment: Thank you very much, that's fixed it!